# Magento - How to create 1 Product that will essentially link to 2 others?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, inventory-management

My questions is basically I have 2 products that can be sold separately and together.

What I want to do is take these 2 individual items, create a new product in Magento for it with a new image that will show both of them together for a combined price.  When this particular item is sold then it will reduce the qty from each of the individual sku's that were created.  Is this possible?

As an example,

SKU 1 - Wii Remote - $30
SKU 2 - Wii Nunchuk - $15
SKU 3 - Wii Remote + Nunhcuk - $45

So when sku 3 is sold it will reduce the qty of sku 1 and 2.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a "bundle" could help you?

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-a-bundled-product

I don't know for sure, because I have never used Magento. I just Googled your problem.

Answer (score 0):

A bundle product will do if your rules are within these:
Points to Remember

```
A Bundle is a “build your own” product type
Bundle Items can be Simple or Virtual products, but without Custom Variants and Options
The Price View of a Bundle can be set to display a price range or “As Low as”
The SKU and Weight of a Bundle product can be set to either “Fixed” or “Dynamic”
Items can have either a preset or user-defined quantity
Items can be shipped together or separately
Bundle product data cannot be imported into your catalog.
```

Means : bundle product cannot have a configurable product within.
so if your SKU1 and SKU2 are not configurable or rather just simple or virtual then you can create a bundle product and sell the way you have stated.

Comment: Is there a way so it does not show the as low as or from price?  We want it to display 1 price as if you are buying one product, so we dont want the customer to select what they want within the listing.

Comment: This display of bundle product is via bundle/product/catalog/price.phtml. You will find  <span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('As low as') ?>:</span> and other code part, modify this .phtml

Answer (score 0):

I don't necessarily agree with the way magento wants us to sell our "Bundles"

It lets users decide which products they want to combine, it's really similar to a "Grouped product".

To me a bundle is predetermined by the store owner, If A is Bought together with B & C, then the customer saves X amount of money... It's not up to the customer to decide what's part of the bundle.

SO I ended up creating the Bundle, adding all the products I want in the bundle as a "Multiple Select", ticked them all as "Default", 
[image: bundles]

and I'm hiding the options with CSS, only showing the price and the add to cart button (Every product has it's own class in ): `body.product-name #product-options-wrapper { display: none }`

So of course if you have thousands of bundles then this won't work for you.

I'm really happy with this solution because 1. It updates the inventory & 2. All of the SKUs are displayed on the invoice! (For me they are also lot numbers)